# Xcode5 lost connection error with C

Tags: c, xcode5

when i build & run my code i get this error

> one exited unexpectedly  lost connection
>
> Program ended with exit code; -1

any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int hour;
    float price, total_price;
    char first_letter;
    printf("Type first letter of worker name> ");
    scanf("%c",&first_letter);
    printf("Type work hours> ");
    scanf("%d",&hour);
    printf("Type price for per hour> ");
    scanf("%f",&price);
    total_price = hour * price;
    printf("%c worker will get money per hour: %f\n",first_letter,total_price);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works for me building on the command line, so the code is OK at least.

Comment: I got it what's problem. Need to use native keyboard. not any 3d part keyboards

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same problem. Use shift+Enter, without the shift it is a Return.

Comment: Your solution worked for me. Any idea why this matters? When I run my command line app in XCode I have to press shift+Return but when I run it from Terminal I only have to press Enter. Further, when I use the Return key on my macbook pro built-in keyboard it always works but the problem only occurs in XCode with the Return button on my external Apple keyboard (silver with low profile white keys)